# Referencing links in a different way

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to C# and asp.net and would like to know the following:
Can I reference jquery library in the following format?

```
src="http://~/sites/booksite/tools/js/jquery.tools.min.js"
```

it does not give a compilation error or anything but want to make sure..

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `~/` (tilde+slash) method of referencing paths is an ASP.NET thing - URLs on elements with `runat="server"` (i.e. server-side controls) will be evaluated and expanded from the relative path (where `~/` is the root of the application or virtual directory.) If the ASP.NET engine isn't doing this, then it doesn't get done.

In order to specify a relative path from the root, you should be able to get away with just the slash:

```
src="/sites/booksite/tools/js/jquery.tools.min.js"
```

Alternatively, apply the `runat="server"` value, and it would work:

```
runat="server" src="~/sites/booksite/tools/js/jquery.tools.min.js"
```

But when using the tilde+slash, then `http://` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

No. if the jquery is local to your site you can use the ~ to represent the root of your site.  Provided that this src attribute is on a control with runat=server.  But providing the http:// is unneeded in that case.

Answer (score 0):

No you must definetly cannot. The "root folder" of your "application" is managed by the server, your application doesn't care if it's in `/` (development machine) or `/prettyapp` (production server).

What you can do however is ask ASP.NET figure out the path for you and fill it in:

```
<script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/sites/booksite/tools/js/jquery.tools.min.js") %>'></script>
```

As a node, don't just use absolute paths (`/something/`) like Mr. Disappointment suggests, your application will die if you deploy it to a virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the right way.

The Tilde will only be processed if the tag has `runat="server"`, so yes you can do it but you shouldn't.

The ONLY reason you would want to specify a full http path to the script file is if you are hosting it via a content delivery network (CDN).

However, jQuery is already hosted on arguably the largest CDN -> Google.  See http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html

So, I would just leverage the resources that they give for free.